# Determine whether all radio button groups have one checked box

Tags: jquery, radio-button, validation

I am making a quiz where each question has a group of radio buttons, like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="quid16" value="answid53" />Answer 1 : foo
<input type="radio" name="quid16" value="answid54" />Answer 2 : bar
<input type="radio" name="quid16" value="answid55" />Answer 3 : joe
<input type="radio" name="quid16" value="answid56" />Answer 4 : blogs
```

Each group gets an id, such as `quid16` above; this id is generated by PHP and not fixed.

When I validate the form submission, I need to check whether all the groups have one checked radio button.

The problem is that I don't know the group ids beforehand. How would I solve this problem?

Comment: Are you using the jQuery Validate plugin or are you doing this from scratch?

Comment: Find all the radio buttons. Iterate through them, creating a property in an initially empty object using the radio button name. If the button is checked, set the value of the property to `true`, otherwise leave it null. When you're done, the properties in the object with `null` values are the radio buttons left unchecked.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can take all radio boxes, starting with "quid", and then:

1. filter the unique names
2. filter the checked values
3. compare 1. vs 2.

Code:

```
var radios = $('[name^=quid]'),
names = $.unique(radios.map(function() {
    return this.name;
})),
checked = radios.filter(function() {
    return this.checked;
});

if (names.length == checked.length) {
    alert('all answers are checked');
}
```

Comment: @Pointy Actually there was something more jQuery'ish that I didn't see before :)

Comment: Thanks jack. I was unaware of the name selectors existance. You're solution helped me out big time.

Comment: @Amelia You're welcome. If my answer was sufficient, consider accepting this answer by clicking the tick-box next to this answer.

Comment: Jack. Yes I want to accept this answer. It seems the tick-box you mentioned just isn't there. Perhaps because this question has been closed?

Comment: @Amelia Read [here](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask) how to accept answers.

Comment: @Amelia, There should be a check mark below the number 3 near this answer. Check [this about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [Attribute Starts With Selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to get elements prefixed with 'quid', and [jQuery.is](http://api.jquery.com/is/) to select elements that are `:checked`. For example:

```
$('[name^=quid]').is(':checked'); //Returns true if any radio buttons are 'checked'
```

Here's an example JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SDXSf/

```
<input type="radio" name="quid16" value="answid53" />Answer 1 : foo <br/>
<input type="radio" name="quid16" value="answid54" />Answer 2 : bar <br/>
<input type="radio" name="quid16" value="answid55" />Answer 3 : joe <br/>
<input type="radio" name="quid16" value="answid56" />Answer 4 : blogs <br/>
<br/>
<button>Test</button>
<script type="javascript">
    $(function(){

    function isOneChecked(selector)
    {
       return $(selector).is(':checked')
    }

    $('button').click(function(){
        alert(isOneChecked('[name^=quid]') ? 'Validated' : 'Please select a radio    button');
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Wait a minute... you want to group by the number after `quid`? So does that mean radio group #1 would be quid01, radio group #2 would be quid02, and so on?

Comment: yes that would be the grouping. However group#1 doesnt necessarily have to be quid01, it could just as well be quid15 quid169 etc. etc.

Comment: I'd go with Jack's answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
if ($('input:radio').is(':checked')) {function()} else {function()}
```

Comment: I don't think this really gets to the heart of the question.

Comment: "But since those quizes can vary from one page to the next..." i think there can't be more than 1 group of radio on the page.